# Loading the 2 most recent files from a folder in an ftp from Linux

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, ls

Good afternoon everyone,
We have the following :

- on server X we have some files spawning every 15 minutes (normally). This files are 2 type - .csv and .log
- we need to grab the most recent 2 files and bring them in the server Q, parsing them in order to remove ":" and replace it with "-" for example;
- load them in an ftp server;

The code is something like this at the moment :

```
`#!/bin/bash

X=ip.address
USER=myuser
SRC_DIR=/home/user/GETFILES/temp/
DEST_DIR=/home/user/GETFILES/input
date1=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`

echo "======================================="
echo "======================================="
echo "======================================="
echo "Here we go $date1 !"
echo "======================================="
echo "======================================="
echo "======================================="

rsync -av --ignore-existing --include="patternforfiles\*.*" --exclude="*" -e "ssh -p port -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" $USER@$X:$SRC_DIR\* $DEST_DIR

\#Removing the ":"
cd temp/
for i in *:*; do
mv -- "$i" "${i//:/\-}"
done

**for i in `ls -Art SRC_DIR | grep filename | tail -n 2`;do** 

**mv $SRC_DIR$i $DEST_DIR;** 

**done**

sshpass -p "password" sftp -oPort=port user@ftp.address \<\< !
lcd /source/directory/
put filename\*.\*
bye
!`
```

bla bla
Cleaning task

If I run as a separate command the ls -Art part works fine, it bring me the last 2 files from the rsync path. If I run in under a script it brings 2 other files then the ones obtained with the previous command...and no idea why.
What am I missing with this for in ls?

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain what is your expectations. `tail -n 2` returns 2 files or less.

Comment: It will put as a list the last 2 files. Using ls -Art is displaying them in a row : file1 file2 file3...
By using the tail -n 2 is putting the most recent 2 files as a list:
file1
file2

Comment: Very nice design. what is the question `it bring totally 2 files...and no idea why. What am I missing with this for in ls?` . Please explain your question, and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Sorry for my bad spelling, I edited the question. In the end, after I modified the variables it started working, I have a feeling I was putting the wrong path in it, having as reference a test path. Now it seems is working without any issue, tested since yestarday night. I also modified the for in the ls -Art part, removing the grep as it was not actually usefull, at least not at this point.

Comment: Excellent update to question. More understood. Suggesting to use `ls` command option `-1` so that you get online single file return per line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggesting there are more then one file per line in the `ls -Art` command.

```
dudi@IL105567WIN:~$ ls -Art
.profile      .landscape  .sudo_as_admin_successful  dev               .motd_shown  .lesshsQ
.bashrc       .vimrc      .local                     .selected_editor  .hushlogin   .viminfo
.bash_logout  .vim        .cache                     .config           .lesshst     .bash_history
```

Using `ls` command with option `-1` or `-l` solves this by printing each file in separate line.

```
dudi@IL105567WIN:~$ ls -1Art
.profile
.bashrc
.bash_logout
.landscape
.vimrc
.vim
.sudo_as_admin_successful
.local
.cache
dev
.selected_editor
.config
.motd_shown
.hushlogin
.lesshst
.lesshsQ
.viminfo
.bash_history
```

Comment: That actually looks very useful at least in my case. Thanks a lot